# Rails app in a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to set up a Rails app in a subdirectory. My server is Cherokee. I have a base url of: 
www.nonsense.com, which is a wordpress blog, and I wish to set up a rails app in, www.nonsense.com/rails_app.

A quick scan of google led me to using: ActionController::AbstractRequest.relative_url_root = "/rails_app"

However, it seems this has been removed in the latest Rails. Any ideas as to the equivalent in Rails 2.3.8?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is configure your Wordpress hosting webserver to direct your "sub" URLs to a Rails application server. The answer to this will depend on what servers you are running and how you have deployed them. Please provide more detail about your environment

Comment: Ah, noted. Its already configured. www.nonsense.com/ correctly leads to my functioning WP installation. www.nonsense.com/rails_app leads to my rails app, but I'm getting a "this page doesn't exist" error. Which doesn't happen when the app is in the root directory, only when in the sub, so I assume it has to deal with the relative_url_root.

Answer (score 9):

For Rails 4/5, you can set this in `application.rb` or `production.rb`:

```
config.relative_url_root = "/app1"
```

Or simply set this environment variable:

```
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/app1'
```

However, I've found that this only prefixes paths to assets. URL paths created by url helpers doesn't respect this setting.

Turns out, there's a bug related to this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5122

This is supposed to have fixed it, but I've not found that to be the case:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18775/files

The documentation for this feature isn't very clear on how exactly it's supposed to work:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root

Maybe try namespacing instead:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

This answer might also be helpful:
[Configuring a Rails 4 app for production in a subdirectory under Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047261/configuring-a-rails-4-app-for-production-in-a-subdirectory-under-apache)

Comment: I've encounter the same problem, `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT` still seems to be broken.

Answer (score 7):

you want to use this in your environment file now:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/rails_app'
```

Source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html