# How do I set the root directory in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails app in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355319/rails-app-in-a-subdirectory)

I'm just learning Rails (2.3.5 - can't upgrade, sorry), and I've got an app running on a certain port which I've mapped a directory to (using a `.htaccess` file). So, website.com/directory is the root for the Rails app. What keeps happening is that I'll click on a link, and it'll try to take me to website.com/controller/method instead of website.com/app/controller/method. How do I change that? It seems like a simple question, but I can't find an appropriate response. It's messing up everything - `javascript_include_tag` is inserting a `link` to website.com/javascripts/ instead of website.com/app/javascripts. I think you get the idea. What can I do to fix that?