# Rails 3 running in subdirectory, assets not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm serving two Rails sites using [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org). Rails1 does not use the asset pipeline but Rails2 does. Rails2 also uses a prefix to differentiate it from Rails1.  For example:

```
http://myhost     -> Rails1
http://myhost/abc -> Rails2
```

Both sites are running, however any reference to assets on the Rails2 site are **not found**.

Here's what my pseudo nginx.conf looks like:

```
http {
    upstream rails1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
    upstream rails2 {
        server 127.0.0.1:3030;
    }
    server {
        location ~ ^/assets/  {
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            access_log off;
        }
        location /abc {
            proxy_pass http://rails2;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://rails1;
        }
    }
}
```

Also,  the routes.rb in my Rails 2 app:

```
Rails2App::Application.routes.draw do

  scope '/abc' do
    resources :projects
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end

end
```

Browsing to `http://myhost/abc/` for the Rails2 app, brings up the page with no css, and the following error:

```
GET http://myhost/assets/application-asdasd.css 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried using `config.assets.prefix = '/abc'` in the production.rb file but it didn't work.  I've also tried different variations in the ngnix.conf file to no avail either.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or missing?

---

**UPDATE**

I'm not quite sure why, but I was able to get this to (incorrectly) work using an @location instead of an upstream.  But I had to move the assets folder from the Rails2 app to the Rails1 app.  Not exactly ideal.

Changes to the server section:

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    access_log off;
}

location ~ ^/(abc)/ {
    root /rails2/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @rails2;
    error_page 404              /404.html;
    error_page 422              /422.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /500.html;
    error_page 403              /403.html;
}

location / {
    root /rails1/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @rails1;
    error_page 404              /404.html;
    error_page 422              /422.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /500.html;
    error_page 403              /403.html;
}

location @rails1 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}

location @rails2 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3355589/417872

Have you tried this?

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/rails_app'
```

I would recommend googleing for how to correctly serve a rails app from a subdirectory. That's the real issue you're dealing with, and a quick search returned several pages of useful looking links.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running Rails 4 on Nginx in production environment. The solution I found was to specify the `root` path for the asset location in `nginx.conf`:

```
location ^~ /assets/ {
    root /home/rails/myapp/public;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Hope this helps