# Configuring a Rails 4 app for production in a subdirectory under Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, subdirectory

There are three major issues I'm struggling with, I appreciate any help for any of them.

**1) How do I configure the Rails app to have `myurl.com/myapp/` as the root?**

I tried in `routes.rb`:

```
scope '/myapp' || '/' do
    # all resources and routes go here
    root :to => "papers#index"

    resources :papers
end
```

and in `environment.rb`, i added this to the top

```
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/myapp"
```

This nearly works, except that `rake routes` doesn't print any route for "/", and `GET myurl.com/myapp/` produces `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/")`

**2) What do it need to tell apache?**

The provider of my shared server suggest to put this to `~/html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^myapp/(.*)$ /fcgi-bin/rails4/$1 [QSA,L]
```

with `/fcgi-bin/rails4` being

```
#!/bin/sh

# This is needed to find gems installed with --user-install
export HOME=/home/kadrian

# Include our profile to include the right RUBY
. $HOME/.bash_profile

# This makes Rails/Rack think we're running under FastCGI. WTF?!
# See ~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/handler.rb
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=1

# Get into the project directory and start the Rails server
cd $HOME/rails4
exec bundle exec rails server -e production
```

When I click any link on the site, the browser url changes e.g. to `myurl.com/fcgi-bin/rails4/papers/1`, where it should be `myurl.com/myapp/papers/1`. How can I prevent that?

**3) How to get the assets working**

I feel like this will be solved somehow together with 1) and 2). However, right now, the app tries to do:

```
GET myurl.com/assets/application-5e86fb668d97d38d6994ac8e9c45d45e.css
```

which procudes a `404 Not Found`. The assets should be under the subdirectoy too, right? How do I tell rails to put / find them there?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few assumptions I'm going to make in order to try and answer your question.

1. I'm assuming there is a static site served at `myurl.com` and that you only want the Rails app to be served on `myurl.com/myapp`
2. I'm assuming your shared hosting provider prefers FastCGI as a way to serve Rack apps (Rails)

Based on those assumptions, I believe that if you:

1. Move your Rails app under the `~/html/myapp` folder
2. Add a `.htaccess` file to `~/html/myapp/public` with contents:

```
    AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi

    Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI 

    RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L] 

    ErrorDocument 500 "Rails application failed to start properly"
```

1. Add a `dispatch.fcgi` file to `~/html/myapp/public` with contents:

```
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
    ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('your_gem_home')

    require 'fcgi' 
    require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../config/environment.rb')
```

1. `chmod +x ~/html/myapp/public/dispatch.fcgi`

the app should start just fine and route just fine...

I don't think you need to worry about setting `config.action_controller.relative_url_root`.

I would also install your gems using `bundle install --deployment` prior to deploying your app.

Finally, the reason you're not getting a root route is because there is no:
`root :to => 'controller#action'` in your `config/routes.rb`

Hope this helps and if not, check out:

[Dreamhost - Rails 3 and FastCGI](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Rails_3#Using_FastCGI) and [FastCGI setup](http://www.kattare.com/docs/faq_view/241) which includes some hints about using `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']`