# Custom route instead of rails_admin /users/sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-admin

I have an app somewhere like myapp.com and `rails_admin` installed. So here is my admin route:

```
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users
```

And ofc admin page is reached in myapp.com/admin. There I can sign in, make request to myapp.com/users/sign_in and this will work nice.

Now:

Lets imagine that my app is reached through myapp.com/uk/ address. So here is changed route file:

```
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => 'admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users
```

Now I can go to myapp.com/uk/admin and get an admin login page. But when I try to login, rails_admin makes a request to /users/sign_in, so it goes to myapp.com/users/sign_in, not to myapp.com/uk/users/sign_in.

How can I fix this thing?

**EDIT:**

ok, and what about when my app is on my server, and procedure is:

1. user goes to www.verycoolapp.com/uk/
2. this app watches my server www.myapp.com

I want my admin panel to be available on www.verycoolapp.com/uk/admin not on www.myapp.com/admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the "root" URL to include the subfolder: [Rails app in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355319/rails-app-in-a-subdirectory)

```
#config/application.rb
config.relative_url_root = "/app1"
```

[Rails guide on the issue](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root)

Comment: Thanks 4 the answer. See the edit, now when I go to www.verycoolapp.com/uk/admin it redirects me to www.verycoolapp.com/uk/myapp/users/sign_in and shows login form. When i log in it makes request to www.verycoolapp.com/users/sign_in

Comment: Sorry about the late reply! Does this only happen with Devise? I.E are the other routes okay? Devise's path structure can be changed to suit if required

Comment: Other routes in my routes.rb are okay, I guess the problem is with devise.