# unable to see rails server, just folder structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

This is the url wherein I'm tyring to run rails:

http://btwnthelin.es/rails/wiki/

it's a subdirectory of the main url.

Is it possible to run apache and rails simultaneously in different places on the same machine?

Why am I unable to see the server landing page?

It's running on port 3000.

I tried to access it with `http://btwnthelin.es:3000` but that also didn't work.

---

Maybe [this](https://www.riscosopen.org/wiki/documentation/show/Running%20Rails%20applications%20from%20subdirectories) is the answer?

Comment: what rails configurations did you make in apache?

Comment: I've just been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zNouhuKaVs). I also did [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355319/rails-app-in-a-subdirectory) but with the directory structure of `rails/wiki`

Comment: you really think we're going to watch that 1hour video?? no way..  just provide the right information if you want an answer