# Rails Mailer does not pick up on the host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Site is in sub-directory `/app`

In development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  host: 'localhost:3000/app'
}
```

Url generated in the mailer `item_url(1)`:

`localhost/item/1`, it should be: `localhost:3000/app/item/1`

How do I replace `localhost` with `localhost:3000/app`?

This is in Rails 4.1.15.

Comment: `/app` is not a valid hostname component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `script_name` did the trick:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { 
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 3000, 
  script_name: '/app' 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on tadman's comment... Your host should only have the 'localhost' portion and a separate port option:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3000
}
```

As for making the app load under /app:

```
config.relative_url_root = "/app"
```

(See see [Rails app in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355319/rails-app-in-a-subdirectory) for details)

Comment: The port should probably be omitted from the `host:`, since it's described in `port:`.

Comment: Host and Port works. `relative_url_root` does not. Getting closer